# Zombies in my laptop: Canopy / Jupyter won't die

Tags: macos, jupyter, canopy

There's a Canopy icon in my dock, but neither pinned nor running.  When I try to launch a .ipynp app, nothing happens.  When I try to force quit the Canopy icon, nothing happens either.

I did `ps gauxww | grep canopy` to see what processes might be running, and got:

```
(p36) [~/Projects/Sensorex/workspace.kds/cp/tools]$ ps gauxww | grep -i canopy
r                16116   0.0  0.1  4680908  18196   ??  Ss   Sun07PM   0:16.97 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-0ec06dfe-3914-4f58-afec-3786f2c050ed.json
r                13071   0.0  0.1  4558316  11408   ??  Ss   Sun02PM   0:14.87 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-3e40bcc2-a743-4d28-836e-f9651822dce5.json
r                  868   0.0  0.1  4892288  19940   ??  Ss   Sat02PM   0:52.56 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-617c9234-eaea-43b0-8e97-bb38eaf9d213.json
r                  826   0.0  0.1  4556268  11424   ??  Ss   Sat01PM   0:20.41 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-fadab8c5-f2a6-4187-a6e4-8a352bc2f3d2.json
r                  821   0.0  0.1  4558316  11408   ??  Ss   Sat01PM   0:20.36 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-52a33bb3-24bf-476e-a1b0-8f89586fae86.json
r                  657   0.0  0.1  4557548  11444   ??  Ss   Sat01PM   0:20.56 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-4da07d8f-abdc-411f-831f-a70c688f7984.json
r                  654   0.0  0.1  4558316  11432   ??  Ss   Sat01PM   0:20.56 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m ipykernel -f /Users/r/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-d123f8fe-7cdc-44d8-af3f-42e280984e4b.json
r                  644   0.0  0.1  4386312   9708   ??  S    Sat01PM   4:48.02 /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Users/r/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/jupyter-notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir /Users/r --config /Users/r/.canopy/notebook/ipython_notebook_config.py
r                54060   0.0  0.0  4267768    896 s001  S+    2:51AM   0:00.00 grep -i canopy
```

Since process 644 seemed to be the ringleader, I killed it.  `ps` now shows NO canopy processes running:

```
(p36) [~/Projects/Sensorex/workspace.kds/cp/tools]$ ps gauxww | grep -i canopy
r                54070   0.0  0.0  4276984    920 s001  S+    2:52AM   0:00.00 grep -i canopy
```

But what's really odd: the icon is still in the dock.  Force quit still has no effect.  Trying to launch a .ipynp document still has no effect.

I've seen this before.  Evidently OS X thinks some aspect of the app is still running, but I don't know how to get things back to normal without rebooting my machine.

Any idea what's going on?

P.S.: I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88)

P.P.S.: And even when I try to restart macOS, I get the message `Your Mac hasn't restarted because "Canopy" failed to quit.`  And -- as I mentioned -- force quit has no effect.  So I need to hard restart macOS.

Answer (score 0):

1) Look for and kill `python` processes, not just "canopy"

2) Unfortunately on Mac, the "open" file association won't work correctly unless the Canopy editor is already open. Alternatively, you can make Canopy User Python your default Python and open your `jupyter notebook` from Terminal. See ["Make Canopy 2 User Python be your default Python"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001454163-Make-Canopy-2-User-Python-be-your-default-Python).

3) The current version of Canopy is 2.1.6, with 2.1.7 due within days. 
To update Canopy, see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).

Comment: Still no joy: After killing off all python processes, `ps gauxww | grep -i python` shows nothing, nor do I see any `canopy` processes, yet there's still a zombie canopy icon in the dock.  I'll try upgrading to the new canopy.

Comment: ... and asking Finder to move /Applications/Canopy.app to trash says `The item "Canopy" can't be moved to the trash because it's open`.